# Concatenate two columns and plot the result into a graph

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a simple example I am trying to do:

I have column A with sample data and column B with others sample data. For personal reasons these samples were separated.

```
Column A     Column B
1            6
2            7
3            8
4            9
5            10
```

I would like to plot a graph with a series which include the column A and B at same line.

Desired result
[image]
My result
[image]

I would like to have a formula for this to add in the data graph options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to edit chart and select combine ranges and select vertically. That should do it.